# C# Specify method via string?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I can do something like this to get a TYPE from a string:

```
Type.GetType("System.Int32, mscorlib")
```

Now let's say I have this:

```
class Program
{
    static int Test(int x)
    {
        return x;
    }
    .
    .
```

I want to specify the Test method in app.config as a string. Is there a standard for this?

I.e. ... converter="ConsoleApplication2.Program.Test, ConsoleApplication2" />

Is there a .Net method already to pull a MethodInfo or preferably the Delegate? Would it work in "all cases" if I get remove the last . section of the part before the comma and get the type on that, then GetMethod for the last part, i.e:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication2.Program");
type.GetMethod("Test")
```

Or are there any gotchas if I do it like that?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve here, but you may be better off looking at implementing an standard interface and specifying the type rather then use reflection to determine the calling method.

Comment: @DavidG -- I want to specify a static method via the app.config. My API will pull it from the app.config and get the Delegate to the static method.

Answer (score 0):

`GetMethods` will return array of MethodInfo objects representing all methods defined for the current Type that match the specified binding constraints.

Use `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to search only the methods declared on the Type, not methods that were simply inherited.

```
MethodInfo[] Methods = type.GetMethod(BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.NonPublic| BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Now get your method with name

More information

[Type.GetMethods Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx)